# How to get class methods and other non-class methods which are NOT covered by unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing

I am using Laravel with PHPUnit testing cases. I am writing unit tests to cover all my functions and class methods. The code is big and new functions added every day.

Is it possible to get function and class methods which are not yet covered by unit tests?

Comment: Do you mean [code coverage](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html)?

Comment: maybe i am wrong, but can this PHPUnit doc attribute give me the list of not covered functions?

Comment: Not by a doc attribute, but usually you'd generate a coverage report after running your tests which lists all functions (and lines) that were covered, which you can use to find out which ones weren't.

Comment: sounds like a manual work, is it possible to get list of functions by not processing manually coverage output but by automatically generated list? i have ~50 classes with ~100 methods in each

Comment: I personally use PHPStorm, which has support for this [built-in](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-coverage.html). Here's a laracast on [how to use it](https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/23).

Comment: i use PHPStorm too, I readed the doc but i have no coverage tool window in View tab, should i install some plugin ?

Comment: I don't *think* so. The window should pop up automatically if you choose to run your tests (from within PHPStorm) with coverage.

Comment: I did setup of php interpreter and phpunit and now it shows 0% for each directory, but i have @covers atribute behind test methods with full class path. what can be wrong?

Comment: Coverage report is based on the last test run and the code actually touched, no the `@covers` attributes. If you only run one test (instead of all of them) coverage will be lower.

Comment: Answer
Me and Dmitry wrote this laravel package for 5.7, but it should work in 6.x too: https://github.com/kilitary/laravel-finder-tests?cc=2354340583434587&ga=345459345394853453453453454453453454